# Identical lines still shown as not identical while comparing

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-cdt, subversive

Trying to make working version similar to revision. After I did `Coppy current change from right to left` I still see grayed line that according to my understanding shows difference. In reality these lines really became identical.
Why they are shown as different:

[image]

Comment: Hit Ctrl+3, enter `Show Whitespace Characters` and select the command to see the changes. Ctrl+3 and `Ignore White Space` to ignore such changes.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if there's hidden characters at play.

If you don't have an easy method at hand to view hidden characters, might be worth pumping each line into an ascii converter, [there's one here](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/):